# resampling or interpolation?

Tags: interpolation, resampling

it is not clear for me which are the differences between resampling and interpolation in the image processing. If I have a geotiff and I would like to improve its resolution, should I use a resampling method such as nearest neighbour, is it right? For instance I have found the gdalwarp function to do this.
What about interpolation methods, i.e. kriging? Is it better if I have data not uniformly distributed? And what if I would like to take into account also the digital elevation model to correct my image?
Many thanks for the help and sorry for confusion.

Laura

Answer (score 8):

There are some relationships between interpolation and resampling.

Resampling implies changing the sample rate of a set of samples.  In the case of an image, these are the pixel values sampled at each pixel coordinate in the image.  In the case of audio, these are the amplitude values sampled at each time point.

Resampling is used to either increase the sample rate (make the image larger) or decrease it (make the image smaller).
Interpolation is the process of calculating values between sample points.

So, if you resample an image you can use interpolation to do it.  There are a lot of interpolation methods - nearest neighbor, linear, cubic, lanczos etc.  Each method has different quality/performance.

If you reduce the sampling rate, you can get aliasing.  This is where you are trying to represent frequencies that can't be represented by the new (lower) sampling rate.  Often resampling will also incorporate filtering (which is NOT interpolation) to avoid aliasing.

If you double the size of an image, you'll end up with gaps in it every other pixel.  Using interpolation you can fill these gaps.
If you increase or decrease the size of an image by some fractional amount, you'd look up interpolated values in the source image which are at fractional pixel positions when doing the resize.

Kriging is typically used to interpolate terrain rather than images.

Increasing the resolution of an image will not improve it - you are not adding any new information to it.

Answer (score 0):

nearest neighbor, linear, cubic, lanczos etc. are not resampling methods (not interpolation methods)?

Resampling is used to make the image larger or decrease it make the image smaller. Ok. We agree. But the pixel are simply duplicates (in the case of larger image), is it correct?
If yes:
no interpolation processes are adopted to do resampling, because interpolation is used to create new values ​​where none existed before (as kriging).
If yes:
I don't understand "if you resample an image you can use interpolation to do it."
resample: i have all point within my image, i only double it.
interpolation: I want to estimate values ​​between the measured values.
is it correct?
Stefano

Comment: Resampling is simply the process of changing the sample rate.  It is typical to use interpolation of some form in conjunction with this process in order to get a better output signal.
When up-sampling with no interpolation then you'd typically end up with zeros instead of duplicates.  duplicates would be formed if you used a nearest neighbor interpolation strategy.  When up-sampling audio, one method you could use is to up-sample by an integer number of times and then convolve the result with a filter kernel before down-sampling by an integer amount.  This does interpolation and antialiasing.